# Where should I add the where clause in a codeigniter model?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I just want to create a sorting query. When I put the `where` clause nothing happened.

What should happen is when `$search_param['type']` has value it should only output the one who has the `$search_param['type']` in sp_archive.SP_Type

Below is the query:

```
function search_data($search_param){
    if(empty($search_param)){
        return array();
    }else{
    $this->db->select("sp_archive.SP_ID, SP_TITLE, SP_RATIONALE, SP_File, GROUP_CONCAT(Tag.Tag_Name) As Tag");
    $this->db->select("ad.Account_LastName AS ADLastName");
    $this->db->select("ad.Account_FirstName AS ADFirstName");
    $this->db->select("ad.Account_MiddleInitial AS ADMiddleInitial");

    $this->db->select("a.Account_FirstName AS AFirstName");
    $this->db->select("a.Account_MiddleInitial AS AMiddleInitial");
    $this->db->select("a.Account_LastName AS ALastName");

    $this->db->select("b.Account_FirstName AS BFirstName");
    $this->db->select("b.Account_MiddleInitial AS BMiddleInitial");
    $this->db->select("b.Account_LastName AS BLastName");

    $this->db->select("c.Account_FirstName AS CFirstName");
    $this->db->select("c.Account_MiddleInitial AS CMiddleInitial");
    $this->db->select("c.Account_LastName AS CLastName");

    $this->db->from("sp_archive");

    $this->db->join('account ad', 'sp_archive.Adviser = ad.Account_ID','left');
    $this->db->join('account a', 'sp_archive.Proponent_A = a.Account_ID','left');
    $this->db->join('account b', 'sp_archive.Proponent_B = b.Account_ID','left');
    $this->db->join('account c', 'sp_archive.Proponent_C = c.Account_ID','left');
    $this->db->join('tag', 'sp_archive.SP_ID = tag.SP_ID', 'inner');

    $this->db->where('sp_archive.SP_Type', array($search_param['type1'], $search_param['type2'],$search_param['type3'],$search_param['type4']));

    $this->db->like("SP_TITLE", $search_param['search']);   

    $this->db->or_like("ad.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
    $this->db->or_like("ad.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);
    $this->db->or_like("a.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
    $this->db->or_like("a.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);
    $this->db->or_like("c.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
    $this->db->or_like("c.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);
    $this->db->or_like("c.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
    $this->db->or_like("c.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);

    $this->db->group_by("sp_archive.SP_ID");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
    }
```

Comment: You should include your PHP code directly in the question, but my first question for you might be are you certain that this `WHERE` clause _should_ be having any effect on the query?  Maybe it just didn't affect any records, or perhaps you didn't code it correctly.

Comment: I think after select. Because Where clause will filter your data according to your condition and then less no of rows will be require to filter for your result

Comment: like query override your where behaviour , add `$this->db->group_start();` before starting like query and at the end add ` $this->db->group_end();`

Comment: I think you are looking for the `where_in` function to allow for multiple queries? Instead of `where`

Comment: Ohh!, I just find the mistake in my code. I did not pass the variables needed by the query like the `search_param['type1']` and i should use `where_in()` for the where clause

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment Your code should be like

```
 $this->db->where('sp_archive.SP_Type', array($search_param['type1'], $search_param['type2'],$search_param['type3'],$search_param['type4']));

 $this->db->group_start();
 $this->db->like("SP_TITLE", $search_param['search']);   

 $this->db->or_like("ad.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->or_like("ad.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->or_like("a.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->or_like("a.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->or_like("c.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->or_like("c.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->or_like("c.Account_LastName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->or_like("c.Account_FirstName", $search_param['search']);
 $this->db->group_end();
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
public function select_where($table,$where)
    {
          $r = $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
        // $sql  = $this->db->last_query();
        //echo $sql;
        $res = $r->result();
        //print_r($res);
        //die;
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: Code Snippets are not meant to be used to format your code! Code Snippets are runnable 

**JavaScript**, **CSS** and **HTML** code blocks to help to create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example!

[how to format my code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

and

[About Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)